# Bound the probability that a point belongs to a set

Tags: pr.probability, expectation, covering, upper-bounds

Let $(a_k)_{k \geq 1}$ be random variables taking values on a finite subset $B$. Assume that
$$
(1) \quad \Pr\Big (\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}d(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[a_k = b]}, [v_\ell(b,\theta_0),v_u(b,\theta_0)])= 0\Big)=1 \quad \forall b\in B
$$
where $d$ stays for distance (i.e., absolute value difference); $v_\ell$ and $v_u$ are real-valued functions of $b\in B$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$; $\theta_0\in \mathbb{R}$ is a *specific* value of $\theta$.

Define
$$
\Theta_n\equiv \Big\{\theta \in \mathbb{R}: \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[a_k = b]}\in [v_\ell(b,\theta),v_u(b,\theta)] \forall b \in B\Big\}
$$

**Question**: Is it possible to find an upper for $\Pr(\theta_0\in \Theta_n)$?

**My attempt so far:**
We have that $E\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[a_k = b]}\Big)\leq v_u(b,\theta_0)$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445629/bound-the-expectation-of-an-average#445629)). By Markov inequality
$$
\Pr \Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[a_k = b]} \geq r\Big)\leq  \frac{v_u(b,\theta_0)}{r}
$$
for each $r>0$. From here?

---

As advised in the comment below, the problem as posed only provides trivial bounds. Therefore, in what follows, I add some additional structure. In particular, I show that
$$
(2) \quad \Pr(a_k=b   | a_{1},\dots, a_{k-1}) \in \big[\nu_{\ell}(b, \theta_0), \nu_u(b,\theta_0)\big] \quad \text{ for all } k, b
$$
is a sufficient condition for (1), in the hope that this can suggest additional relevant details.

Proof of (1):
From (2), we have that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \Pr(a_k=b   | a_{1},\dots, a_{k-1})\in \big[\nu_{\ell}(b, \theta_0), \nu_u(b,\theta_0)\big] \text{ for all } n 
$$

Let
$$
S_n(b)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \left({1}_{[a_k=b]}- \Pr(a_k=b| a_1, \dots, a_{k-1})\right).
$$
Observe that the sequence $(S_n(b))_{n\geq 1}$ is an $L^2$-bounded
martingale. Therefore, $S_n(b)$ converges almost surely as $n\to +\infty$. Further, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} S_k(b)$ converges to the same limit as $S_n(b)$.

Let
$$
Q_n(b)\equiv \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1_{[a_k=b]}- \Pr(a_k=b| a_1, \dots, a_{k-1}\right).
$$

Observe that
$$
Q_n(b) = n S_n(b)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} S_{k}(b).
$$

By the convergence of $S_n(b)$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} S_k(b)$ to the same limit, $\frac{1}{n}{Q_n(b)}$ converges almost surely to 0 as $n\to +\infty$.

Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[a_k=b]}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \Pr(a_k=b| a_1, \dots, a_{k-1})\overset{a.s.}{\to} 0 \text{ as $n\to +\infty$.}
$$
Therefore, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[a_k=b]}$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \Pr(a_k=b| a_1, \dots, a_{k-1})$ have the same limit points which belong to $ \big[\nu_{\ell}(b, \theta_0), \nu_u(b,\theta_0)\big] $ and (1) holds.

Comment: The only upper bound under these very general conditions is the trivial bound $1$, which is attained when e.g. $v_\ell(b,\theta)=0$ and $v_u(b,\theta)=1$ for all $b,\theta$. You need to specify $v_\ell(b,\theta)$ and $v_u(b,\theta)$ and, I think, the $a_k$'s. However, I am afraid that even then the only upper bound will usually be the trivial bound $1$. You will probably have to rethink the whole thing.

Comment: You said you were assuming (1). So, why do you need to prove it? Also, the added proof is, not of (1), but of something else (if it is a proof of anything). You should try, first of all, to address the specific concerns raised in my previous comment.

Comment: As I wrote, the added proof is not a proof of (1). Also, (1) does not need to be proved. What needs to be addressed is my comments on $v_\ell(b,\theta)$ and $v_u(b,\theta)$. Otherwise, you cannot possibly get a reasonable answer to your question: as I also said, "The only upper bound under these very general conditions is the trivial bound $1$."

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand the English of "the added proof is not a proof of (1)": do you mean that its steps are wrong?

Comment: I will make one more attempt to try to help you here. The conclusion of your proof involves conditional probabilities, whereas (1) does not. So, your proof may be a proof of something, but it is not a proof of (1). I have not checked steps of your proof. However, I'll reiterate just one more time: "(1) does not need to be proved. What needs to be addressed is my comments on $\nu_{\ell}(b, \theta) $ and $\nu_u(b,\theta)$".

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks. the proof shows that (2) is a sufficient condition for (1). that's why the final statement involves conditional probabilities ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote before in a comment, the only upper bound on $\Pr(\theta_0\in\Theta_n)$ under these very general conditions is the trivial bound $1$.

Indeed, suppose that for some $b_*\in B$
\begin{equation}
    \Pr(a_1=a_2=\cdots=b_*)=1
\end{equation}
and for all $b\in B$
\begin{equation}
    v_\ell(b,\theta_0)=1(b=b_*)=v_u(b,\theta_0). 
\end{equation}
Then $\Pr(a_k=b)=v_\ell(b,\theta_0)=v_u(b,\theta_0)$ for all natural $k$ and all $b\in B$. So, condition (1) holds and $\Pr(\theta_0\in\Theta_n)=1$ for all natural $n$.